# Laravel can't found a stored file 404 NOT FOUND

Tags: php, laravel, file, upload, laravel-8

posting this again because I didn't find to solution yet.

Laravel can't found the file storage/app/public/upload
when I use`http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/upload/The_fileName.x` I get `404 not found`
I've tried `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/app/public/upload/The_fileName.x`  too.

what should I do ?

In `DocumentController` :

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'doc' =>  "required",...
    ]);

    $document = new document();

    $file = $request->file('doc');
    $filename=time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension() ;

    // I've tried these too, one by one and still get the same error .
    //$file_path = public_path('public/upload');
    //$file->move($file_path, $filename);
    //Storage::disk('local')->put($file, $filename);
    //request('doc')->store('upload', 'public');
     
    $file->storeAs('public/upload', $filename);
    $document->doc = $request->input('doc', $filename);
    $document->candidate_id = $candidate_id;
    $document->save();
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You're currently storing in `public/upload`, so the URL path would be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/The_fileName.x`. Where does `The_fileName.x` live in your file system?

Comment: @aynber http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/The_fileName.x doesn't work too, the file in (C:\Users\user\Documents\project\storage\app\public\upload)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Laravel document File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-urls), you need to create a symbolic link at `public/storage` which points to the `storage/app/public` then you can  access the file with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/The_fileName.x`.